# Syntax Error escaping characters

Tags: javascript, escaping

I'm getting **SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list** but I don't know what's wrong.

```
$(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
    var input = $(this),
    numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
    label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, ''); /**PROBLEM**/
    input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
});
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.btn-file :file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {
        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
            log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;
        if( input.length ) {
            input.val(log);
        } else {
            if( log ) alert(log);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are using commas instead of semicolons

Comment: the commas follow `var` so are ok

Comment: [There doesn't seem to be any syntax errors](https://jsfiddle.net/3gd5zd7c/)? Did you "auto-fix" the error when you created the example?

Comment: Do you need to replace \ in the text from a file input?  You only ever get the file name.

Comment: mmm this is weird... Is it matter if I'm working on localhost?

Comment: You can get the full path from the value of `input type="file"` when using file protocol in IE, but not in any other browser (maybe in Edge too?). If you're using http(s) protocol, all browsers will obfuscate the value for JS. There was a comma after `label` assignment in your original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My objective was to style a **bootstrap's input filetype** so I tried to set a script like that (not working for me on localhost / MAMP) for showing file names and nr, once uploaded.

In my research I've found [this bootstrap's script](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/) that do the job. It's a workaround but could help future visitors.